# Get random data from database

Tags: php, mysql

I am new to php. I am creating small online exam application. I have created one Question table in MySql and want to display only one question on page. After submitting answer of that question, display another question on page. Can anyone help me how can i do this? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

SELECT * FROM questions  ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 4

Answer (score 0):

**Edit 2**
Here is update pseudocode to fix a few problems with the original code.

Basically the change here is getting the all question ids from the database and then shuffling. This avoids the case of missing ids in the auto-increment sequence, which is likely.

The other change from the old code is grabbing all the selected questions from the database instead of one at a time. Not sure what I was thinking there.

Here is some psuedocode:

```
// Get all questions ids. This should be fine since there shouldn't be too many cases where you will have more than 1000 questions.
$questionIds = db.selectIdsFromQuestionsWhereTypeIsSports();

// Shuffle array so the question ids are out of order
shuffle($questionIds);

// Number of questions you want
$quizLength = 5;

// select your questions    
$selectedQuestions = array_slice($questionIds, 0, $quizLength);

// Now fetch all data for selected questions
$quiz = db.fetchByWhereIdIn($selectedQuestions);

// Now do whatever with your question
```

**Original
I wouldn't use the MySQL `rand` function. It does not provide great performance if you have a lot of rows. Additionally, you face the chance of selecting the same question again.

So what I would do is retrieve your set of questions from the database and then shuffle in php.

If you have thousands of questions, then I would suggest randomly generating a sequence of numbers that relate to your auto-increment id. If you aren't using auto-increment ids, then this won't work.

So if you want to ask 10 questions and have 100 questions in your database, then generate 10 numbers between 1 and 100 for example.

The one downside of this approach is if you have holes in your auto-increment sequence. If you don't have too many numbers, you can just throw it out and randomly pick another number.

Here is some psuedocode:

```
// Get a count of your questions from the database
$totalQuestions = db.count();

// Generate an array sequence/range
$questionIds = range(1, $totalQuestions);

// Shuffle array so the numbers are out of order
shuffle($questionIds);

// Store your questions    
$quiz = array();

// Number of questions you want
$quizLength = 5;

// Now you can retrieve questions like so
while (count($quiz) == $quizLength) {
   $question = db.fetchById(array_pop($questionIds);
   if ($question != null) {
      $quiz[] = $question; 
   }
}
// Now do whatever with your question
```

Answer (score 0):

set asked question ids in session as comma seprated

```
$_SESSION['asked_question_ids'] = $asked_question_ids;
```

get random questions which is not already asked using question ids from session

```
$asked_question_ids = '3, 4, 5, asked queston ids from session'

SELECT * FROM questions WHERE qid NOT IN ($asked_question_ids) ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1
```